# "irq_to_desc" undefined?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

everybody. 
I need to use $irq_to_desc in my project, but despite the fact I included all h files it needs, gcc still emits ""irq_to_desc" undefined!" messages. I found something on the topic here http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.kernel.kernelnewbies/34403 but I still dont understand how to fix this prroblem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you can use `irq_to_desc()` in a module.

If `CONFIG_GENERIC_HARDIRQS` isn't defined, then `irq_to_desc()` is `#defined` as a macro in `include/linux/irqnr.h`. Since the variable it references, `irq_desc`, isn't in an `EXPORT_SYMBOL` or `EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL` declaration, I don't think you could link a module using that variable into the kernel -- only statically compiled in-kernel code can use it.

If `CONFIG_GENERIC_HARDIRQS` is defined, then a function `irq_to_desc()` is declared in `include/linux/irqnr.h` and defined in `kernel/irq/irqdesc.c`. There are *two* definitions of `irq_to_desc()` in `kernel/irq/irqdesc.c` depending upon the value of `CONFIG_SPARSE_IRQ`. There is no corresponding `EXPORT_SYMBOL` or `EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL` declaration for the function, so it can't be used in modules -- only statically compiled in-kernel code.

Comment: Well, I dont think I really got it. Anyway, if there is any function or macros which I can use in module to get irq_desc by irq number.